# Is it possible intercept a method from @ManagedBean? If not, there alternatives?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, cdi, interceptor, managed-bean

I'm new to JSF-2 and CDI (I'm from Spring world).

I want to intercept a method from @ManagedBean but my Interceptor class is never called. Is it possible to do?

**LogInterceptor.java**

```
@Interceptor
public class LogInterceptor {

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object log(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("begin method interceptor");
        Object methodReturn = ctx.proceed();
        System.out.println("end method interceptor");

        return methodReturn;
    }   
}
```

**RoleMB**

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class RoleMB extends BaseMB {

    @Interceptors(LogInterceptor.class)
    public void preEditRole(Role role) {
        ...
    }
}
```

**beans.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">

    <interceptors>
        <class>br.com.preventsenior.services.log.LogInterceptor</class>
    </interceptors>

</beans>
```

The `log(InvocationContext ctx)` is never called.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Java EE interceptors work only on CDI managed beans and EJBs, not on JSF managed beans.

So, you've basically 2 options:

1. Change JSF bean management annotations by CDI bean management annotations (`@Named` et.al.)
2. Intercept on an EJB method instead which is in turn invoked by JSF managed bean. In a sane Java EE application, the real business logic belongs in EJBs anyway.

Comment: Good response, in JSF 2.2 all JSF beans should be CDI beans, so this won't be an issue in Java EE 7.

Comment: We can do this in JSF 2.1 though too, can't we, @LightGuard? Did something else change in 2.2?

Comment: @DavidS: JSF 2.2 introduced a new scope which isn't backwards compatible with `@ManagedBean`, hereby hinting that they stopped supporting `@ManagedBean`. It will be deprecated in Java EE 9 or perhaps already 8.